# How to Trigger Blue-Green Deployment for AWS RDS from Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, blue-green-deployment

I'm currently working on upgrading AWS RDS  postgres instance major version  using blue/green deployment but I'm unsure about how to handle blue-green deployments for AWS RDS  instances through the Terraform.

I have used registry code also where they specified about enabling blue green update
 `blue_green_update = { enabled = true }`
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/latest/examples/blue-green-deployment
Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve blue-green deployments for AWS RDS using Terraform?

I am expecting provisioning  Blue-Green Deployment for AWS RDS from Terraform

Answer (score 0):

If you have, as mentioned, added the following code snippet inside of your `resource "aws_db_instance"` then planning & applying is the only thing you need to do. Enabling this configuration option for the first time will also result in a new deployment being triggered, even if you leave all the settings unchanged (parameter groups, server version, etc).

```
  blue_green_update {
    enabled = var.db_blue_green_update_enabled
  }
```

AWS Terraform provider will take care of:

- provisioning the green instance
- syncing it with the blue instance
- triggering the switchover
- deleting the old instance

No interaction from operator side is needed during this operation.

From my experience the only noticeable impact was that a batch worker connected to the (likely) old instance for a few seconds after the switchover and couldn't modify any data because it was already in readonly mode at that time.